# Mongoose InjectModel model type when using Schema without decorators

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm trying to implement user management using Nest.js and Mongoose. My DB design tool has generated for me Schema in `new mongoose.Schema({ .... });` format, so for now I have schema ready. The problem I've encountered is when trying to `@InjectModel` in User's service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('User') private userModel: Model<>) {}

  async getAll() {
      //code
  }
}
```

`userModel` in constructor must have it's type, but since my Schema was generated without using decorators (and my own classes), I can't use for example `Model<User>`, because User as class just doesn't exist here, so the question is:
Do I have to add separate User class with same fields as my Schema has, or there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: yes have to add separate User type

Comment: Thank you, I'll do it that way

Comment: @Zając Could you please provide the updated code snippet?

Comment: I don't have it anymore, sorry